# Handlng python project and file organization

Tags: python

I am developing python functions in different .py files (example DisplayTools.py, CollectionTools.py...) in order to import them as tools in a more general file Start.py. It works fine if all the files are in the same directory. I can say in Start.py "import DisplayTools" ... 
But how to organize those in a more project way and more user-friendly (where they only have to work on the Start.py file). For example having such an file organization :

- Project/

  Start.py

  - Tools/

    DisplayTools.py

    CollectionTools.py

I've read the use of `__init__` files but how they works, where to put those files and what are they containing ?

Please if you have some help to give me in that way to organize my project.

Many thanks

Answer (score 5):

I'd refactor your code organization just a bit and give your toplevel directory a more descriptive name.  Today, I pick `happy_bananas`.  So let's say you organize your files like this:

```
happy_bananas
   start.py
   DisplayTools.py
   CollectionTools.py
```

then all you need to do is add an empty `__init__.py` file and you can use it just like any other package, e.g.:

```
happy_bananas
   __init__.py
   start.py
   DisplayTools.py
   CollectionTools.py
```

And now if you can do:

`from happy_bananas import DisplayTools`

just like you would have before.

Now, to get this into your system, you need to package it and use an install script.  You can do this using `distutils` or `setuptools` but perhaps the simplest existing description of how to do this is in Zed Shaw's [Learn Python The Hard Way Exercise 46](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex46.html).  You really can just copy/paste those files as described there and end up with a directory structure like this:

```
happy_bananas
   setup.py
   tests
       test_happy_bananas.py
   happy_bananas
       __init__.py
       start.py
       DisplayTools.py
       .
       .
```

Then, when you have your setup script written, you can go into your folder and run `python setup.py install` (or `python setup.py develop`) and be able to `import happy_bananas` in any file.

On a separate note, the naming convention in python is to use snakecase for file and function names.  So instead of `DisplayTools.py`, it would be better to rename it `display_tools.py`. CamelCase is usually reserved for class names only.

Comment: Nice answer, but may be overkill for the OP.

Comment: I don't realy get the use of setup. According to the file tree I propose in the question, doing from tools import DisplayTools.py is not working (even with an empty `__init__` file in the Tools directory)... [Thanks for your comment on namin convention]

Comment: Packaging is a much more complex evolution I expect. I'll try to handle this later. I want the user fill in the Start.py according to functions present in Tools/DisplayTools.py for example !

Comment: @user1187727, I may have misunderstood your question. I thought you were asking about how to make your package available to other programs. The `setup.py` file lets you install your package into your path, so it's available to the interpreter (so you can use `import your_package` from *any* location, just like you can with any module in the standard library. If this doesn't quite make sense yet, don't worry, but I'd encourage you to take some time, read a book (like [Learn Python the Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/)) and get acquainted with more of Python.

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters i would simply change my files to have a set of functions and some main code since the files could also be executed.

For example:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    dosomething()
```

Then in the main, you simply import the other scripts and you can use the functions used there without actually running the script.